# How to create a circle and on hover of that circle it should become bigger

Tags: jquery

I want to create a circle and on hover of that circle it should become bigger.

Here is the Example: http://www.ivanbayross.com/jquery_effect1/.

The above works perfect with jQuery v1.7.1.

I want to make the same code work with jQuery v1.9.1.

Can some one please let me know what changes I have to make in order to make it work with jQuery v1.9.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of browser support do you need this to work for? These effects are possible with CSS3 web-transitions and no javascript. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/96H3y/

Comment: Hi Antony, Thanks for your reply. I am looking for all Modern Browser support, IE7, IE8 and IE9. The example you provided in jsfiddle.net is not giving the same kind of effect as the example.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe `border-radius` is the only way to create circles in CSS. This unfortunately isn't supported by IE7 or IE8.

Comment: @mkb Well, i think IE7 and 8 don't qualify as 'Modern Browser' at all.

Comment: Ok. Well you can still achieve that kind of effect with CSS3, look at this http://jsfiddle.net/96H3y/3/, but not in older versions of IE.

Comment: It's also worth noting that IE9 [doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility) CSS3 transitions.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly how can I get it work in IE9...

Comment: @mkb the example you've given doesn't animate in IE9 and isn't circular in IE7 or 8. For the animation in IE9 you can use jQuery (which is what my answer is using).

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume we have a `span` set to display as a block element:

```
<span></span>

span { display:block; }
```

Circles in CSS can be made easily with the `border-radius` property.

```
span {
    border-radius:100px;
    border:100px solid #5ae;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
```

This will create a perfect 100px-radius blue (#5ae) circle.

To make this larger on hover (`mouseover`), we simply need to make use of jQuery's `animate()` method. Increasing the `border-radius` and `border-width` to the desired size:

```
$('span').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'border-width': 200,
        'border-radius': 200
    }, 500);
});
```

To then decrease this on `mouseout`, we simply revert the changes:

```
$('span').on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'border-width': 100,
        'border-radius': 100
    }, 500);
});
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/YJsew/1/).

[**Second JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/YJsew/2/) using individual radius positions instead of just `border-radius`.

[**Third JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/YJsew/3/) changing the `borderColor` of the element with jQuery UI (as per comments).

Comment: Hi James thanks for your reply. But when I hover the span, for a second the same become a square. This is not exactly as the example I have provided. Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: What browser are you using? It remains circular in Chrome.

Comment: I've modified it to use each individual radius position instead. This works in IE9, IE10 and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/YJsew/2/ **Edit:** This also works in Firefox 20.0.

Comment: There is a difference in the work my example work and the example you have provided. In my example, there is a big circle in grey. Inside that there is a small circle in green. On hover of the green, the outer circle (grey) becomes black. Where ass in your example the circle increase more towards the left and right side..

Comment: Your question simply stated "I want to create a circle and on hover of that circle it should become bigger.". I didn't know you wanted it exactly like the example. For changing colour (with jQuery) you'd need to include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)'s ["Color Animation"](http://jqueryui.com/animate/). To get the circle inside another circle you'll want create a second circle and position the new one inside it.

Comment: Here it is with jQuery UI included, changing the `borderColour` from #5ae to #a5e (and back): http://jsfiddle.net/YJsew/3/